# VBA Excel 2013 Headline / Footline manipulation

Tags: vba, excel, header, formatting

I am currently working on a VBA tool that sets the headline and footline in an Excel document for all sheeds in it automaticly, it opens when a document is opened and the user can ether import the head and footline from another document, write it in the fields in the gui window.
To prevent the user from having to type in everything if he maybe just needs a small change, the window has all values already filled in from the current document.

My problem is now that I don't know how to split the incoming string up into format parts and the  actual shown text parts, (it is not neccesary to split the formatting parts themselves up).

till now I used Replace() to simply erase known format parts and add them manually at the end, but that won't cut it for varying titles.

Attemts with using a For loop to cut the incoming string at the & symbols failed because for once the user could use Titles with & symbols and the last format does directly continue with the actual text (&K03+039Appendix a color variable leading into the title part Appendix)

I also can't use any parts of the table itself since this will be a universal too for all kinds of tables.

So I want to know if there is a way to split a title string into actual text parts and format parts.

An Input String with every format I could come up with was this:
&"Algerian,Fett"&14&S&X&K03+039Appendix C - Opera
while Appendix C - Opera was the Title.

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: Entschuldigung, ich verstehe nicht Deutsch :D

Comment: As far as I knot the only german word is Fett -> Fat, and is a formatting part, if I accidently wrote some other german parts, let me know.

Comment: @Ismalith, your header is in German

Comment: better now. :-) Is there anything a good old "split(string, ";") " can solve in your problem? I don't see what your problem is... BTW if you use & to concatenate, the space before & is mandatory

Comment: I don't define the way the string is written, it is created by word itself when format change are made by the user, like changeing the size or color, which is the problem, every use of the split() function would let the last format parameter together with the name and since these parameter isn't defined in lenght, I don#t have any idea how to get the name and parameters seperated.

&K03+039Appendix with Appendix as the name and K03+039 as a color parameter would be the core of the problem, but could also be &SAppendix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I now developed a solution to my problem that works for me, it isn't beautiful but works.

It can split up a given string into formatting parts and a text part, however it can't work with && within a title, that needs to be taken care of before using this method.

It also doesn't know the formatting of page numbers, since I didn't need it but that can be fixed very easily.

```
Public FullLine As SeperatedLineParts
```

Private Function InformationHandler(text As String)
    Set FullLine = New SeperatedColumnParts
    Dim param As String
    Dim textPart As String
    Dim co As Integer

```
'Stops the function when "text" is empty
If text = "" Then
    FullLine.text = text
    FullLine.format = ""
    Exit Function
End If





'Splits the incoming "text" in single Symbols
Dim singleSymbols() As String
ReDim singleSymbols(Len(text) - 1)
For co = 1 To Len(text)
    singleSymbols(co - 1) = Mid$(text, co, 1)
Next



'switch case variables, helper for seperating the "text"
Dim isParam As String   ' Boolean Value as a String, to use it for the switch cases
Dim wasText As Boolean  ' Remembers if the last part was a textpart or a format part, if it was a text and now a format part is following, they will be sepperated
isParam = "False"       ' Remembers if the current Symbol is a textpart or a format part
wasText = False
FullLine.parts = 1      ' remembers the number of parts with different formats

' This loop splits Format and Textparts and writes a Chr(3)||Chr(2) Marker between the different formatted parts
For co = 0 To UBound(singleSymbols)
    Select Case singleSymbols(co) + isParam

    Case Chr(38) + "False"          ' If a & symbol appears it will start a new parameter except if another & follows (&&)
        If singleSymbols(co + 1) = Chr(38) Then
        textPart = textPart + "&&"
        co = co + 1
        isParam = "False"
        Else

        If wasText = True Then      ' If a & follows after a textsegment a new part will be created except when another & follows (&&)
            textPart = textPart + Chr(3) + "||" + Chr(2)               ' Chr(3) and Chr (2) arte the permitter  and  that split a following formatpart from a leading textpart
            param = param + Chr(3) + "||" + Chr(2)
            FullLine.parts = FullLine.parts + 1
            wasText = False
        End If

        isParam = "True"
        param = param + "&"
        End If


    ' Identifies all single letter commands
    Case "L" + "True", "C" + "True", "R" + "True", "I" + "True", "E" + "True", "X" + "True", "Y" + "True", "B" + "True", "U" + "True", "S" + "True", "D" + "True", "T" + "True", "F" + "True", "A" + "True", "N" + "True", "Z" + "True", "G" + "True"
        param = param + singleSymbols(co)
        isParam = "False"

    ' Identifies all size commands
    Case "1" + "True", "2" + "True", "3" + "True", "4" + "True", "5" + "True", "6" + "True", "7" + "True", "8" + "True", "9" + "True"
        param = param + singleSymbols(co)
        If IsNumeric(singleSymbols(co + 1)) Then
            co = co + 1
            param = param + singleSymbols(co)
        End If
        isParam = "False"


    Case Chr(34) + "True"           ' If the " symbol appears at the beginning of a command it will be a longer command till another " symbol ends it
        Dim coun As Integer
        param = param + singleSymbols(co)
        For coun = co + 1 To UBound(singleSymbols)
            param = param + singleSymbols(coun)
            If singleSymbols(coun) = Chr(34) Then
                co = coun
                coun = UBound(singleSymbols)
            End If
        Next
        isParam = "False"


    Case "K" + "True"               ' Identifies all color commands
        param = param + singleSymbols(co)
        For coun = 1 To 6
            param = param + singleSymbols(coun + co)
        Next
        co = co + 6
        isParam = "False"


    Case Else                       ' Identifies all normal text symbols
        textPart = textPart + singleSymbols(co)
        wasText = True

    End Select
Next

' Writes the format and the text parts into the "FullLine" object, wich now contains these parameters as well as the number of parts
FullLine.format = param
FullLine.text = text
End Function


'Function for making a string out of an array while shorten it at the beginning for the given amount
Private Function ArrToString(inpu() As String, shortenBy As Integer) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = shortenBy + 1 To UBound(inpu)
        ArrToString = ArrToString + inpu(i)
    Next

End Function
```

I know it is a monster and will probably hurt every more experienced programmer, but it is the best I could come up with till now.

edit: it still has the issue that if there are format symbols within the text, it will take only the last text part as text and everything that is between a format part will be seen as a Format as well.

Is there any more effective way to get this done.

Edit: Redesigned the whole function, it is now able to deal with format changes within a text and the &&, also the commentary was improved to make it changeable for other user.

Also write a classmodule with:

```
Option Explicit
Public parts As Integer
Public format As String
Public text As String
```

for the function to work.

edit: the Chr(3) and Chr (4) symbols don't work on this side, and the example comments for what you should see in your output don't show them, so your result will differ from what is shown here.
For all that matters these symbols are symbols that are unlikely to be used by any headline in excel, and can be changed without any further changes in the rest of the code.